# installing LVP over existing engineered hardwood

Tags: vinyl-flooring

Can I install LVP over existing engineered hardwood floor that are glued to a concrete slab?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll probably need more info; is there moisture under the slab? more details about the existing flooring?

Comment: No moisture.  I was told to put a vapor barrier down and I thought if the existing flooring was there could I use it as the vapor barrier.